# Description(and many attributes) for User Control are not displaying info

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, attributes

I want to show some description information of my User Control in the Propereties toolbox. 
After writting some attributes for the control:

```
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    int id;

    [Description("Get or Set the main name of the css class to apply")]
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    [Description("Get the number of nodes")]
    public int NodesCount
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true),
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(""),
    Description("The Uri to find the Xml file"),
    Editor(typeof(System.Web.UI.Design.XmlUrlEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string XmlPath { get; set; }
```

There are no answer from the toolbox

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: +1 weird, it works with Controls but not with UserControls

Comment: @onof that's exactly my observation too. I guess it's a limitation of webusercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed this yet, but I have read that you if you create the WebUserControl in a separate project and add the .dll reference, you will then get the design time support you are looking for.